# swift 2.x how to use try catch

Tags: ios, swift2

here is my async Image Loader code.

compile error and warning.

warning >>> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression.

my first code >>>

```
 let getImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: imageURL)!)!)
 completion(result: getImage!)
```

but this code has error, wifi connected not error

wifi disconnected has error.

so i want use to try-catch.

```
do{
   let getImage = try UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: imageURL)!)!)
   completion(result: getImage!);
}
catch
{
    print("NOT CONNECTED")
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am ashamed for my little english T_T.....

Answer (score 0):

UIImage(data: data) does not throw any exception so you cannot just use try and catch

Instead you can use something like this

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "")!){
    if let getImage = UIImage(data: data) {
         completion(result: getImage);   
    }
}
```

Comment: But `NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: imageURL)!)` does throw one, right?

Comment: @mad_manny that don't throw error, if u want throw, u have to custom your own error, if u option click the `contentsOfURL ` u see it dont throw error, but something like `contentsOfFile ` does

Comment: Like @Tj3n mentioned  NSData(contentsOfURL:  )  does not throw an exception but if you use NSData(contentsOfURL: , options:  ) it will throws -- you can see these things from auto completion menu on xcode